# how to include an Embedded attribute to json return object spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, jackson

I have a Kotlin Spring Boot application with these following entities:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
class Users(
    @Id
    var username: String = "",

    @JsonIgnore
    var password: String = "",

    @JsonIgnore
    var enabled: Boolean = false,

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "authorities", joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "username")])
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "users")
    private var authorities : MutableSet<Authorities> = mutableSetOf()
)
```

and

```
@Embeddable
class Authorities(
    var authority: String
)
```

When I call this endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/users")
fun getUserById(@RequestParam(value = "username") username : String) : ResponseEntity<Users>{
    val optionalUser = usersService.getByUsername(username)
    return if(optionalUser.isPresent) ResponseEntity.ok(optionalUser.get())
    else ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
}
```

it returns correctly, as you can see in this json:

```
{
    "username": "test@gmail.com"
}
```

But it doesn't return the list of authorities that belongs to this user, and I wanted to have it returned. My question is: How could I do it?

Thank you so much for helping

Comment: Most likely because `authorities` is declared `private`…